# Отказ от контроля зависимости от сервисов?

Tags: c#, архитектура

У Марка Симана в его книге Dependency  Injection есть пример, когда он отказывается от контроля над зависимостью ProductRepository (страница 63):

> Я собираюсь отказаться от контроля над зависимостью ProductRepository.
>   Как продемонстрировано в следующем листинге, я лучше буду полагаться
>   на что-нибудь другое, чтобы получить экземпляр с помощью конструктора
>   HomeController. Этот паттерн называется Constructor Injection
>   (внедрение через конструктор) – как и кем создается экземпляр не
>   является заботой HomeController.

```
Листинг 2-5: HomeController с паттерном Constructor Injection
public partial class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ProductRepository repository;
    public HomeController(ProductRepository repository)
    {
        if (repository == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("repository");
        }
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var productService = new ProductService(this.repository);
        var vm = new FeaturedProductsViewModel();
        var products = productService.GetFeaturedProducts(this.User);
        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            var productVM = new ProductViewModel(product);
            vm.Products.Add(productVM);
        }
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

У меня такой вопрос: а почему не бы и не избавиться от зависимости и от ProductService, там тоже стоит new и этот сервис тоже можно было передать на конструктор.

Это какое-то упрощение было сделано для облегчения материала или Марк в реальных приложениях не видит потребности отказа от этого слоя абстракции?

(Описываемые им сервисы не являются сервисами инфраструктурными или операционного слоя - а это сервисы бизнес-слоя, так что нет необходимости абстрагироваться от них -- как-то так я мог бы это объяснить)

Comment: например потому, что сервис может использоваться только в одном методе, а репозиторий во всех

Comment: Мне кажется, Марк просто показал на конкретном классе, как перестать контролировать одну их его зависимостей (репозиторий). Вы можете взять это за образец и сделать то же самое с сервисом - это не будет ничему противоречить.

Comment: @tym32167 Противоречить-то не будет... Но и пользы особой не будет, разве что в требованиях будет "написать тесты на контроллеры"

Comment: в смысле пользы не будет? Вынос зависимости в конструктор - это и есть суть инверсии зависимости, или я не понял вас